# Several Select option with the same name

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

I have problem, I tried several tries I could but nothing works.

I have this select name ***category***

```js
$("#category").change(function() {

  if ($(this).val() == "Strings") {
    $("#instrument").show();
    $(".Label").show();
    $("#instrument2").hide();
    $("#instrument3").hide();
    $("#instrument4").hide();
  } else if ($(this).val() == "Percussion") {
    $("#instrument2").show();
    $(".Label").show();
    $("#instrument").hide();
    $("#instrument3").hide();
    $("#instrument4").hide();
  } else if ($(this).val() == "Keyboard") {
    $("#instrument3").show();
    $(".Label").show();
    $("#instrument").hide();
    $("#instrument2").hide();
    $("#instrument4").hide();
  } else if ($(this).val() == "Woodwind") {
    $("#instrument4").show();
    $(".Label").show();
    $("#instrument").hide();
    $("#instrument3").hide();
    $("#instrument2").hide();
  } else {
    $(".Label").hide();
    $("#instrument").hide();
    $("#instrument2").hide();
    $("#instrument3").hide();
    $("#instrument4").hide();
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="category" class="form-control" rows="1" name="category" required>
  <option value="Strings">Strings</option>
  <option value="Percussion">Percussion</option>
  <option value="Keyboard">Keyboard</option>
  <option value="Woodwind">Woodwind</option>
</select>
And this select name instrument
<br>
<select id="instrument" class="form-control" rows="1" name="instrument" required>
  <option value="Guitar">Guitar</option>
  <option value="Violin">Violin</option>
  <option value="Cello">Cello</option>
</select>
<select id="instrument2" class="form-control" rows="1" name="instrument" required>
  <option value="Drum">Drum</option>
  <option value="Xylophone">Xylophone</option>
</select>
<select id="instrument3" class="form-control" rows="1" name="instrument" required>
  <option value="Harpsichord">Harpsichord</option>
  <option value="Piano">Piano</option>
</select>
<select id="instrument4" class="form-control" rows="1" name="instrument" required>
  <option value="Flutes">Flutes</option>
  <option value="Saxophone">Saxophone</option>
</select>
```

The problem is whatever I choose on select option it gives me a value of `'Flutes'` ,also I have a css to hide those not chosen by category, and show instrument on category change.

Comment: What exactly is the issue? This should work fine. What do you mean by "*I choose on select option it gives me a value of 'Flutes'*"? What is `.Label`?

Comment: What's the problem? Seems to work fine.

Comment: This is what i'm getting, when I did click on category and choose guitar, It gives me the value Flutes even though i picked Guitar

Answer (score 0):

crude, short answer:

1) Put a data-property on category options:

```
<option data-instrument='instrument2'>Percussion</option>
```

2) Get data-attribute of selected category option:

```
var selectedInstrument = $('#category option:selected').data('instrument');
```

3) hide all instruments

```
$('select[name=instrument]').hide();
```

4) show instrument from selected category

```
$('#' + selectedInstrument).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone

I already solved it by using dom id to set name instrument or disable

```
document.getElementById("sub_title8").name='disabled';
document.getElementById("sub_title8").name='instrument';
```